# Algebraically Closed Quotient Fields

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-domain

> It is well-known that if the quotient field of a commutative noetherian integrally closed domain $R$ is algebraically closed, then $R$ is a field.

The proof is easy: let $r_0 \in R$ and choose $r_i \in R, \ i \geq 1$ such that $r_i^2=r_{i-1}$ (this is possible because the quotient field of $R$ is algebraically closed and $R$ is integrally closed). Now consider the chain $Rr_0 \subseteq Rr_1 \subseteq \cdots $. The rest of the proof is straightforward.

> A more interesting fact is that we don't need to assume that $R$ is integrally closed, i.e. if the quotient field of a commutative noetherian domain $R$ is algebraically closed, then $R$ is a field. Is there an easy proof of this? (This is Exercise 4.2, page $90$ of the book *Integral Closure of Ideals, Rings, and Modules*, by Craig Huneke and Irena Swanson (2006)).

Comment: How does the rest of the proof go?  You have $Rr_n = Rr_{n+1}$, so $r_n = ar_{n+1} \Rightarrow r_n^2 = a^2 r_n$.  Iterating you get $r_1 = a^{2^k}r_2$.  What does this show?

Comment: So $r_{n+1}=ar_n=ar_{n+1}^2$ for some $a \in R$ and hence either $r_{n+1}=0$ or $r_{n+1}$ is a unit. Thus either $r_0=0$ or $r_0$ is a unit.

Comment: After taking a look in your book, the problem is finally solved. Unfortunately I was not really aware of this Mori-Nagata-Theorem.

Comment: Actually, I am a bit disappointed by your research effort. After my very first answer, the only remaining flaw in my argument was that the integral closure might be non-noetherian. After looking into your book, I immediately see, that the pages straight before the given exercise deal with a theorem which ensure the noetherianness of the integral closure under some assumption (dimension at most two). Even if you cannot make sure yourself, that the assumption can be satisfied in your case, you should at least have told me about that theorem...

Comment: The book is not "my book", I haven't read a single page of that book. The question came up naturally as I was studying algebraic number theory. I was trying to extend the fact that the ring of algebraic integers is not noetherian.  
Anyway, thank you for your time and your proof which is quite nice and easy if one knew the Krull–Akizuki theorem.

Comment: Ok. But I still wonder why you have not taken a look at the preceeding chapter of the exercise. There was a high chance you would find there some results, which help you with your problem, wasn't there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $R$ is no field, i.e. there is some prime $P$ of height $1$. Then $S:= R_P$ is noetherian and one-dimensional. By Mori-Nagata-Theorem, the integral closure $\overline S$ is also noetherian (This is on pages 89/90 in your book). Hence we can apply the known case to $\overline S$ and get that $\overline S$ is a field. $S \subset \overline S$ is integral, hence $S$ is also a field. But $S$ was the localization at a height $1$ prime, hence not a field. Thus our assumption was false and $R$ is a field.

Comment: For $\dim S=1$ it's actually called the [Krull-Akizuki Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%E2%80%93Akizuki_theorem).